# Add CSS class to anchor element in TinyMCE

Tags: magento, tinymce

I'm using Magento with TinyMCE, and currently it does not support assigning custom CSS class to anchor element through user-friendly interface:

[image]

I tried adding this:

```
extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick|class]"
```

to setup.js, to settings var, but it didn't help. 
How would I add custom class to `<a>` element in tinymce?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ADVlink supports only classes for the starting point of the anchor - here is it possible to chose a class from a pulldown, but not for the target.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible at least in TinyMCE v4. The option you are looking for is called **visual_anchor_class**. All you have to do is to add the following line to your TinyMCE configuration:

```
visual_anchor_class: 'my-custom-class'
```

And all anchor links you create will get a class 'my-custom-class'.

(Manual: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#visual_anchor_class)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a custom rightclick menu and an own popup.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already saw the option in other implementations :/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but have you tried the advlink plugin? This provides a dropdown for css classes, that you can define in the settings with `advlink_styles`:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:advlink

Answer (score 0):

You can use link_class_list https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/link/#link_class_list

**Example:**

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins: "link",
  menubar: "insert",
  toolbar: "link",
  link_class_list: [
    {title: 'None', value: ''},
    {title: 'Dog', value: 'dog'},
    {title: 'Cat', value: 'cat'}
  ]
});
```